# an ME thrown into the world of electrical engineering - what does ME mean?

Tags: meaning

> Granted, there are many good teachers out there and you might have gotten the
>   basics, but time and too many “status reports” have dulled the finish on your
>   basic knowledge set. If you are like me, you have found a few really good
>   books that you often pull off the shelf in times of need. They usually have a
>   well-written, easy-to-understand explanation of the particular topic you need
>   to apply. I hope this will be one of those books for you.
>   You might also be a fish out of water, an **ME** thrown into the world of electrical
>   engineering, who would really like a basic understanding to work with the EEs
>   around you. If you get a really good understanding of these principles, I guarantee
>   you will surprise at least some of the “sparkies” (as I like to call them)
>   with your intuitive insights into the problems at hand.

What is an ME?

Comment: Obviously, EE there refers to "electrical engineering", so ME should refer to some kind of engineering that begins with an M, probably "Mechanical Engineering" or "Mechatronics Engineering".

Comment: On second thought, "EEs" there seems to refers to "engineers" rather than "engineering".

Comment: This is highly context-specific. It might have helped if OP had included the paragraph heading **OVERVIEW For Engineers** from [the original context](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AUHqhqn7mRMC&pg=PR8&lpg=PR8&dq=%22an+ME+thrown+into+the+world+of+electrical+engineering%22&source=bl&ots=NDXrwX_lu6&sig=STbGHlqYZmekThZI5OcFkkG_CvQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nVreU4etIuyW0QXanIC4Bw&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22an%20ME%20thrown%20into%20the%20world%20of%20electrical%20engineering%22&f=false)

Comment: I don't know... the line "ME thrown into a world of electrical engineers" was enough for me.

Comment: If one reads the preface of the book OP has extracted his quote from, there's no doubt ME refers to Master Engineer. Just as EE refers to electrical engineer. A little google search told me Master Engineer is often used for someone who has a Master in Engineering.

Comment: @Laure Um, what? "There's no doubt" is not accurate. Your interpretation makes no sense in the context. Why would someone with a master's degree in engineering be a fish out of water when working with electrical engineers? They'd need to be a different kind of engineer for that statement to work, such as *mechanical*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An **ME** in this context can be a:

> **Mechanical Engineer** (my best guess in this case)
>
> **Marine Engineer**
>
> **Model Engineer**
>
> **Master of Engineering**
>
> **Materials Engineer**

Also note that it is commonly used for **Medical Examiner**.

Comment: You may find this acronym finder useful: http://www.acronymfinder.com/ME.html

Comment: Master Engineer is often used for someone who has a a Master in Engineering. Sites like Linkedin have a "Master Engineer" search, and see this video [Difference Between a Master Engineer & MSEE](http://www.ehow.com/video_12256305_difference-between-master-engineer-msee.html)